# How do I view which objects have been stored locally in Parse?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

My goal is to see which `PFObject`s have been saved locally with the Parse's Local Datastore. I can save objects with `myObject.pinInBackground()` and I can retrieve them with `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` given an `objectId`.

So do I have to store the `objectId`s to see which objects have been stored locally? Isn't there a better way to list all the objects saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query local datastore objects by calling the `query.fromLocalDatastore()` method before executing the query.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-querying-the-local-datastore